# Multiple when statement working on wholedata set

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am working on a data of selling items. For example we can take Jeans here. Now every Jeans can have multiple styles in it like - Torn, Basic, Rugged, Faded etc. 
I want to create a table of how many listings i have in each of these design styles. Now Data is in json format, so first i extracted them but when I apply case statement with multiple when statement (with like as operator) then 2nd when statement does not work on wholeset of data. How to fix this issue without increasing length of my code

Data set is in this format:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use split method for that. Split on '/' then apply logic.

but it is violation of 1NF.

[Please see the below article](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php)